How can I verify the time-invariance of the general solution of an RC circuit?
In my Signals and systems class, we're working on an assignment with different RC and RCL circuits, their differential equations and laplace transforms. One of the things the assignment asks, is to analyze the characterstic equation of the RC circuit, and from the general solution of its differential equation, analize and make the system be Linear and Time-invariant (LTI). The issue is that I'm stuck on the last step for making the system time-invariant.
Here is the general solution for the RC circuit:
$$y_t = S_1\{x_t\} = x_t \cdot \frac{1}{R} + \left(y_o - \frac{x_0}{R}\right) \cdot e^{\frac{-t}{RC}} - \frac{1}{R^2C} \int_{0}^{t} x_\tau \cdot e^{\frac{-(t-\tau)}{RC}} d\tau$$
to make the system be linear, the Initial conditions must be 0:
$$y_t = x_t \cdot \frac{1}{R} - \frac{1}{R^2C} \int_{0}^{t} x_\tau \cdot e^{\frac{-(t-\tau)}{RC}} d\tau$$
Now, to verify that the system is time-invariant, i have to add a temporal shift in the input signal, and check if the output signal is the same if I apply the same temporal shift in the output signal, where $x_1 = x_t(t-t_0)$, $y_1(t) = S_1\{x_1\}$ and $y_2(t) = y_t(t-t_0)$:
$$y_1(t) = x_{(t - t_0)} \cdot \frac{1}{R} - \frac{1}{R^2C} \int_{0}^{t} x_{(\tau - t_0)} \cdot e^{\frac{-(t-\tau)}{RC}} d\tau$$
$$y_2(t) = x_{(t - t_0)} \cdot \frac{1}{R} - \frac{1}{R^2C} \int_{0}^{t - t_0} x_{(\tau)} \cdot e^{\frac{-(t-t_0-\tau)}{RC}} d\tau$$
$$v = t+\tau; dv = d\tau; \tau \rightarrow t-t_0, v \rightarrow t; \tau \rightarrow 0, v \rightarrow t_0$$
$$y_2(t) = x_{(t - t_0)} \cdot \frac{1}{R} - \frac{1}{R^2C} \int_{t_0}^{t} x_{(v-t_0)} \cdot e^{\frac{-(t-v)}{RC}} dv$$
$$y_1(t) \neq y_2(t)$$
by multiplying everything with the Heaviside function, in theory $y_1 = y_2$. The thing is that the only difference between the two functions are the integral limits. My professor says that the Heaviside function has the "property" of making the limits of the integral change, for example:
$$\int_{a}^{b} x(t) \cdot H(t) dt = \int_{0}^{b} x(t) dt$$
The thing is that on my $y_2$, the integration variable is not $t$, its $v$, and I dont know if that "property" applies to all integration variables (weird) or there is something more behind it that I can use.
I currently dont know what to do to make the two expressions be equal.
I wasnt able to find anything about that "property" in the suggested class book (Soliman, Samir & Srinath, Mandyan (1999)), nor in wikipedia or by searching on google.

Your example of the Heaviside kernel "property" is correct if $a \leq 0 \leq b$.  Notice that $H(x)$ is $0$ for $x < 0$ and is $1$ for $x \geq 0$, so deletes the contribution to the integral for $x$s less than zero.  If instead $0 \leq a \leq b$, the $H$ is just "multiplying the integrand by $1$" on the entire interval of integration, so does nothing.  Alternatively, if $a<b\leq 0$, the $H$ is just "multiplying the integrand by $0$" on the entire interval of integration, so zeroes the integral.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function for more on this function.

@EricTowers Thanks for the confirmation! The only thing is that $H(t)$ is technically "completely outside" of $a$ and $b$ of the intergal, because of the different variables. I'm 100% sure that the integral wont have a contribution when $t<0$, but the thing is that when $t>0$, the integral starts to contribute from $t_0$ to $t$. So, if $t = 0$, the integral will evaluate from $t_0$ to 0, instead of not contributing nothing because it integrates from 0 to 0, making the system not linear and time-variable

$$\int_{0}^{t} x_{(\tau - t_0)} \cdot e^{\frac{-(t-\tau)}{RC}} d\tau
= \underbrace{\int_{0}^{t_0} x_{(\tau - t_0)} \cdot e^{\frac{-(t-\tau)}{RC}} d\tau}_{=0} +
\int_{t_0}^{t} x_{(\tau - t_0)} \cdot e^{\frac{-(t-\tau)}{RC}} d\tau
=\int_{t_0}^{t} x_{(\tau - t_0)} \cdot e^{\frac{-(t-\tau)}{RC}} d\tau$$
Hence, $y_1(t)=y_2(t)$.

Could you elaborate more please? how is that integral equal to zero? Since I cant integrate something that i dont know what could be ($x_t$), I think of it from a "primitive" point of view, and I can only think of $F(t_0) - F(0) = 0$

I assume that your signal x(t) is causal, meaning $x(t)=0, \forall t<0$...

@fpp : That is $x(t) = H(t)x(t)$.

I should ask my professor then, he never said anything about the input signal being causalized. In case it's not causalized, is there any alternative solution?
